# An English expression for the easiness with which fish are caught

Tags: phrases, slang

Is there an English word or phrase whose meaning indicates how lucky a person is to get a fish to bite?

In my local language, we have a phrase specific to fishing: "clom-giriwil". 'Clom' means casting the line or sinking the bait, and 'giriwil' means getting the fish to bite and catching it. So, 'clom-giriwil' refers to how easy it is and how lucky a person is to get a fish for the day.

Comment: Would that be part of a saying, such as “as easy as clom-giriwil”?

Comment: I'm just seeing "good fisherman" or similar. It's possible there is a slang term in angling communities. Do you want a commonly used expression, or a technical fishing term? And are you OK with a phrase rather than a single word?

Comment: We call a place (usually a specific spot in a lake or bay) where the fishing is good a [honey hole](https://www.waywordradio.org/is-honey-hole-offensive/).

Comment: Does 'An English expression for the easiness with which fish are caught' mean 'An English expression describing that it is all too easy to catch fish' or 'A way to express in English, on a scale of 1 - 100 say, the easiness with which fish are caught on a particular day by a particular person ...'?

Comment: to take the bait, hook, line and sinker.

Comment: Are you trying to say the person is naturally lucky in most things they do, or was particularly lucky in this one instance? It would help if you gave an example sentence that shows how you would like to use the term in English.

Comment: Of course, you could always say that catching fish is as easy as shooting fish in a barrel.

Answer (score 1):

> 'clom-giriwil' refers to how easy it is and how lucky a person is to
> get a fish for the day

For a possible equivalent phrase that emphasizes *luck* and *ease* (and coincidentally happens to be very suitable for fishing):

> The fish are practically **falling/jumping into your lap** today.

> **fall into someone's lap** (phrase)
>
> (also **drop into someone's lap**)
>
> (of **something desirable**) be acquired by or happen to someone **without
> any effort** being made on their part.
>
> *I was looking for a women writer of the past to promote (with a text out of copyright), and this book **fell into my lap**.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fall_into_someone%27s_lap)

---

> But Santiago went without catching a single fish—not for one or two
> days—but for eighty-four days. How did he, a veteran fisherman, fail
> to catch some of those fishes which were **falling into his lap?**
> [P.G. Rama Rao; Ernest Hemingway's *The Old Man and the Sea*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ernest_Hemingway_s_The_Old_Man_and_the_S/nFtv6YbkoGwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20were%20falling%20into%20his%20lap&pg=PA92&printsec=frontcover) (2007)

> Fishing for Ancestors
> ...
> Neither fish nor ancestors are going to just
> **fall into my lap**, except for that time on Frog Creek; but that is another story, and I digress.
> [Pat Richley; *DearMYRTLE's Joy of
> Geneology*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dearmyrtle_s_Joy_of_Genealogy/EXLfBNeyK5gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=good%20fishing%20they%20will%20fall%20into%20your%20lap&pg=PA69&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> This would be the only fresh food I ate during my time on the ocean,
> with the exception of one supper that, almost literally, **fell into
> my lap**.
> [Roz Savage; *Rowing the Atlantic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rowing_the_Atlantic/rHkvqxH1ik4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20would%20literally%20fell%20into%20your%20lap&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

In the specific case of fishing, this expression is sometimes modified to **jump into someone's lap** (since on occasion fish can actually jump into your lap):

> 'Good luck, William. May the nets find the fish freely!'
> 'Good luck,
> Jacquim. May the fish **jump into your lap!**'
> 'Good fishing, Frances. May
> the lake bestow a reward for your efforts!'
> [Danny Fahey; *The Tree
> Singer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Tree_Singer/ABXHDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20jump%20into%20your%20lap&pg=PA84&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> And even if you go to the river's brink and sit down by the water's
> edge, the chances are that no fish will **jump into your lap**. Thus
> it is with the agent who stays in his office to insure the men who
> drop in to buy policies—Such men run the risk of starving to death.
> [William Alexander; *The Successful Agent*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Successful_Agent/vjQpAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=fish%20jump%20into%20your%20lap&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover) (1917)

Comment: When I was 13, I won a fishing contest in the Boy Scouts when a fish jumped into my lap in a canoe. We were on a week-long canoe trip, and this happened within sight of pullout on the last day. I managed to keep the fish in the canoe and it was the biggest "caught" all week. I hadn't even been fishing, and some of the kids were fishing all week :)

Comment: @PhilSweet Since you took the Scout Oath, we know your fish story isn't a fish story. :-)